# What do the "Unknown" hex error codes in my SEL logs indicate?

Tags: linux, datacenter, ipmi, ipmitool, oem

I dumped the SEL logs from my entire fleet and I have a bunch of occurrences where the SEL entries do not provide any info. So far I've had these entries show up numerous times:

Unknown #0xff | | Asserted
Unknown #0xfe | | Asserted
Unknown #0x1a | | Asserted
Unknown #0x19 | | Asserted
Unknown #0x76 | | Asserted
Unknown Err Reg Pointer | | Asserted

I'm guessing the error code are OEM specific, but how do I go about interpreting the codes. I've checked online and I can't find any error code mappings across the vendors that I use.